# Parsing JSON from HTTP response

Tags: javascript, php, json, prestashop, prestashop-1.5

Suppose i have a URL http://example.com/product/12345 which contains lines of codes. That URL is a product page from an ecommerce website, and within that page lies an "Add to Cart" button.

When that button is clicked, it send an HTTP POST regarding the viewed product and returns the following JSON response :

```
{
"products": [
{
"id":            722,
"link":          "http://example.com/product/123123",
"image_link":    "http://example.com/prodcut/image/thumb.jpg",
"image_width":   "45",
"image_height":  "45",
"quantity":      1,
.... and so on...
```

I'd like to know whether it is possible to parse the response without knowing which function calls it, because :

1. That page is composed of multiple views (which is rendered from different controllers)
2. I've tried to do things like :

   console.log(response.products), or;
   console.log(products)

yet all gives "undefined" error...

Can anyone help me on this ? Thanks very much.

Comment: Where's your JS code that makes the POST call?

Comment: @CharlieS that is exactly the problem, i am having difficulties finding it. It is buried somewhere in one of the views. That is why i want to know whether it is possible to parse JSON response without knowing which JS function that triggers the POST call ?

Comment: Perchance you are looking for [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

Comment: @J.Bush yup that is possible, but i just need to know what should i call it ? i tried to do JSON.parse("products"), where "products" being the object in question. But it throws an error saying "products" is not defined.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan The string there is parsed by the function to be the name products, not the string. Try `JSON.parse('"products"');` instead.

Comment: @JeremyRIrawan Sorry, misinterpreted the question. I'm assuming that your issue is that you are being passed back a string, which represents a JSON object. You need to parse it before you can take response.products. So something like : `var parsedResponse = JSON.parse(response);` I don't know what the request was so I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can point you on exact files, if that will helps:

1. /themes/yourtheme/js/modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js if does not exists look at /modules/blockcart/ajax-cart.js

look as the code below comment line "//send the ajax request to the server"

2. And JSON answer formed in Smarty template file `blockcart-json.tpl` in `/themes/yourtheme/modules/blockcart/` or `/modules/blockcart/`

so, if you will place console.log in ajax-cart.js in

```
success: function(jsonData,textStatus,jqXHR)
            {
                console.log(jsonData.products); // not parsed json here of course
                ...
                },
```

it should works.

Comment: This is by far the closest answer i can get, i can now access the returned JSON response. Thanks for hinting the exact location of the file. However i need to access that result in different view. I guess i just need to make a global variable so that i can access it from different view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use **JSON.parse(response)** for converting to Json object and to convert to string again use **JSON.stringify(response)**